# Local stack says started but throwing different errors `Error forwarding request: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray

Tags: python-3.x, localstack

I am getting this when I start make infra using localstack

```
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
cannot import name 'dns_server' from 'localstack_ext.services' (unknown location)
Starting mock S3 (http port 4572)...
Starting mock SNS (http port 4575)...
2019-09-21T13:11:08:INFO:localstack.multiserver: Starting multi API server process on port 
51492
Starting mock SQS (http port 4576)...
Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 4569)...
Starting mock Lambda service (http port 4574)...
Starting mock CloudWatch Logs (http port 4586)...
Ready.
```

But when I do http://localhost:4569 it throws error and doesnt show it started.
Below are the errors I am getting

```
2019-09-21T13:15:05:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: the 
JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users//workspaces/others/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 240, 
in forward
path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers)
File"/Users//workspaces/others/localstack/localstack/services/dynamodb/dynamodb_listener.py", 
line 35, in forward_request
data = json.loads(to_str(data))
File"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/init.py", line 341, in loads
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

Error 2:

```
2019-09-21T13:14:11:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request:'QueueUrl' Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users//workspaces/others/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 240, in forward
path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers)
File "/Users//workspaces/others/localstack/localstack/services/sqs/sqs_listener.py", line 53, in forward_request
self._set_queue_attributes(req_data)
File "/Users/*****/workspaces/others/localstack/localstack/services/sqs/sqs_listener.py", line 245, in _set_queue_attributes
queue_url = req_data['QueueUrl'][0]
KeyError: 'QueueUrl'`
```

Please help on this its a been a blocker for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because I was hitting http://localhost:4569 which isn't a user interface. So its throwing error.But if I create tables using aws cli and do some operations it just works fine without any issue.